# Device token is nil when using iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, crash, nsstring

my app got rejected by the apple review team. 
They send me a crash file that says:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000



2 CoreFoundation  0x2e8c0e40 +[NSException raise:format:] + 108
3 Foundation      0x2f1e7500 -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] + 84
4 TheApp          0x000aaa3a -[UserSignInViewController userEmail:userPassword:]     (UserSignInViewController.m:175)
```

This crash occurs when logging in to the app, using an iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.

First of all I get the device token via "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:" in the AppDelegate.m (first time the app is launched) and save it tmp. to a static variable:

```
NSString *tmpDT = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken]
                    stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

// Set tmp device token in DataStorage

[PSDataStorage setDeviceToken:tmpDT];
```

When the user is logged out and wants to login to the app an URL with parameters is created by appending strings:

```
//...

// get device token from DataStorage

NSString *deviceToken = [PSDataStorage getDeviceToken];

NSString *fullURL = @"https://.../.../....json?email=";
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:userEmail];
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:@"&pw="];
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:userPassword];
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:@"&client=ios"];
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:@"&device_token="];
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:deviceToken];
```

UserSignInViewController.m:175 references to:

```
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:deviceToken];
```

It seems like the deviceToken is nil. I'm also handling the case, that an user disabled PNs via:

```
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
```

I'm really confused.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: a)If the app runs, and you get the device token but its nil, b)you store nil using PSDataStorage, c) then the app runs again. Then do you have checks in place to ensure the fullURL code is not getting run if the device token is nil? If not then that's why you have a crash. What specific thing is it you are confused about?

Comment: I tested it on iPhone4 and iPhone5. During the development there was not such problem. As I said, it only occurs on the iPhone 5s.
Also the login process is called only once. So c) is not relevant. 

You're right. I will implement a check wether the deviceToken is nil or not. I should have done this already in the beginning. 

But one more question: why should the devie token be nil even when "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:" is called?

Comment: If your app is running right after the device boots up you might very occasionally get a nil token. When I get the token I have a small retry algorithm and if didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError gets called I'll try immediately again, if it fails again maybe wait a few seconds and then try again. I've seen an initial call fail and the retry succeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont know the processes of the review team, but maybe they test the apps on a clean device. However it's strange that this does not effect iPhone4 / 5.

Comment: As an aside, have a look at NSString stringWithFormat - it can replace all of those appends with a single line.  Since your problem occurs on 5S you may have a race condition where one thread is using data that has not yet been set up on another.  You should look at perhaps posting a notification once the device token is available and then performing the registration

Answer (score 1):

A device token is `NSData`, if you want to use it in a string you'll need to convert it to hexadecimal format. Try using the [`NSData+APNSToken`](https://github.com/aporat/NSData-APNSToken) cocoapod to convert the `NSData` to a `NSString`.

Comment: Check the second code snippet. I'm donig it right there.

Comment: It's been mentioned before this is not a robust way of obtaining a string from the `deviceToken` parameter. You're relying on the description method which may change in the future.

Comment: Okay, I'll check that as well. Thank you.